# How to sort two files for duplicates in python

Tags: python

I have two lists: biglist.txt and deletelist.txt. I need to print all lines in symbols.txt that does not have an exact match with deletelist.txt on a line by line basis. Here is my code so far. It will sometimes go into the `if found_dup == False:` line without found_dup being false. Where am I going wrong?

```
f = open("biglist.txt", "r")
g = open("deletelist.txt", "r")
h = open("uniquelines.txt", "a")
found_dup = False
for x in f:
    for y in g:
        if x == y:
            found_dup = True
    if found_dup == False:
        h.write(x)
    found_dup = False
f.close()
g.close()
h.close()
```

Comment: you should provide an example of the file content and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("biglist.txt", "r") as f:
     biglist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
with open("deletelist.txt", "r") as g:
    deletelist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in g]

uniquelineslist = list(set(biglist).symmetric_difference(set(deletelist)))

with open("uniquelines.txt", "w") as h:
    for item in uniquelineslist:
        h.write("%s\n" % item)
```